# Error when declaring variables - Oracle Pl/Sql

Tags: plsql, syntax-error

```
create or replace PROCEDURE hello_world
IS
    DECLARE
       message varchar2(20) := 'Hello, World!';
    BEGIN
       dbms_output.put_line(message);
END;
/
```

I'm getting an error when declaring the variable message (A red underline between message and varchar2).

When I run the procedure it says:

> PROCEDURE HELLO_WORLD compiled
>   Errors: check compiler log

When I execute it. then it shows this:

> Error starting at line : 10 in command -
>   execute hello_world
>   Error report -
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00905: object HR.HELLO_WORLD is invalid
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Note: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer to do all this.

Answer (score 1):

To see the compiler error after a `CREATE`statement, run `show error`.

In your case it's the `DECLARE`. That is not needed inside a stored procedure.

The following should work:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE hello_world
IS
   message varchar2(20) := 'Hello, World!';
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(message);
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But it doesn't output hello world when i execute it.

Comment: And when i execute the stored procedure, it just shows anonymous block completed. It doesn't output 'Hello, World!'. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: You need to run `set serveroutput on` to see the output of `dbms_output`